# How do I display logo when using LinkedIn to log into 3rd party websites

Tags: linkedin-api

We have developed a website where we offer the ability to log in using your LinkedIn profile. The LinkedIn dialogue box that appears, requesting user name and password, has the ability to display the company logo. Can anyone tell me how to ensure our company logo is displayed here during the logon process? Thanks.

Comment: Have you done ` Configuring your LinkedIn application` ? see more https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Comment: Hi - thanks - but yes, we have done this - and you can log into our site using your LinkedIn details. The problem is that the LinkedIn dialogue box that appears, requesting user name and password, has the ability to display our company logo (i.e.there is a blank space for it). I just can't find out how to make our company logo appear in this space.